# proving that concave function is bigger than g(x)=x

Tags: functions

given $f(x):[0,1];[0,\infty)$ which is a Concave function, in other words for every $x,y,λ$ in $[0,1]$ the following is true:

$f(λx + (1 − λ)y) ≥ λf(x) + (1 − λ)f(y)$

Given the above formula, I need to prove that $f(x)≥x$ given that $f(1)=1$

**Note**: I tried to prove that by using Proof by contradiction technique, but didn't work.
I supposed that there is a point $t$ in which $f(t)<t$

Comment: Please typeset using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @KeeferRowan done, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(\lambda) = f(\lambda \cdot 1 + (1-\lambda) \cdot 0) \geq \lambda f(1) + (1-\lambda)f(0)= \lambda + (1-\lambda) f(0). $$

Then note that $(1-\lambda) \geq 0$ and $f(0) \geq 0$, hence $(1-\lambda) f(0) \geq 0$. Thus $f(\lambda) \geq \lambda + (1-\lambda)f(0) \geq \lambda + 0 = \lambda.$

Comment: $f(x) \geq 0$ definition (as the codomain is $[0,\infty)$. $-x\leq 0$ since $x \in [1,2]$. Thus $f(x) \geq 0 \geq -x$. If that doesn't answer your question, I would recommend asking another question. Generally, we recommend one question per post. Also please mark the answer as accepted if your question has been resolved.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake the question should be: how can I prove that in [1,2]()≥(−+2) (In other words, () now is defined in [0,2] please note that the field of values for λdidn't change and is still [0,1]